# Calculate tax total agains php set variables

Tags: php

I am having the darndest time trying to auto calculate taxes in php.  This is what I have so far :

```
<?php
// Formats a number so it appears as such : 55.12, instead of 55.12354
function invoiceNumFormat($number){
    return number_format($number, 2);
}

$tax_rate = 7.5; //Sets Tax Rate

// Retrieves Subtotal, utilitzes NumFormat function to round to hundredths place
$invoice_subtotal = isset($invoice['invoice_subtotal']) ? invoiceNumFormat( $invoice['invoice_subtotal'] ): 0;

//Multiplies subtotal against tax rate to retrieve $tax_amount
$tax_amount = invoiceNumFormat( $invoice_subtotal*$tax_rate/100 );

// Shows Grand Total(subtotal + tax)
$invoice_totalled = $invoice_subtotal + $tax_amount;

//Displays Totals
<span>'.$invoice_subtotal.'</span>
<span>'.$tax_amount.'</span>
<span>'.$invoice_totalled.'</span>
?>
```

I have an output of a subtotal showing "3116.88" which is correct, but the tax showing for that amount is ".32" and the grand total is "3.23".  Can anyone tell where I have gone wrong?

Comment: i tried your code with $invoice_subtotal = 3116.88; //hard coded the value, this resulted me fine, total:3116.88, tax : 233.77, Grand total : 3350.65. so what i think is, there is some wrong value under $invoice_subtotal variable.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 troubleshooted some more, figured out all totals come out FINE whenever I take out my invoiceNumFormat function.  The problem now is, I still need to round that to a dollar amount...

Comment: dollar amount!! can you be clear with this please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup got it!

```
$invoice_subtotal = isset($invoice['invoice_subtotal']) ? invoiceNumFormat( $invoice['invoice_subtotal'] ): 0;
```

the problem is in the above line.

what happens here is, you utilized the function `invoiceNumFormat` when the subtotal value is set, when you pass `3116.88` then it returns `3,116.88` which is not an integer.

so change the line to

```
$invoice_subtotal = isset($invoice['invoice_subtotal']) ? $invoice['invoice_subtotal'] : 0;
```

Comment: I used your solution, in addition i had to have a $tax_amount, and a $tax_amount2(one needed the function), as well as a $subtotal, and $subtotal2(same thing).  I whipped them around as needed to get the output I desired.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You first format numbers, then calculate `$tax_amount` and `$invoice_totalled`. But by this way you perform operations on **string values**, so you can obtain undesired values.

You have to perform **all** math operations with float values and to format variables only at the output.

```
$invoice_subtotal = $invoice['invoice_subtotal'];
$tax_amount       = $invoice_subtotal * $tax_rate / 100;
$invoice_totalled = $invoice_subtotal + $tax_amount;

echo '<span>'.invoiceNumFormat( $invoice_subtotal ).'</span>
<span>'.invoiceNumFormat( $tax_amount ).'</span>
<span>'.invoiceNumFormat( $invoice_totalled ).'</span>
';
```

Comment: I wish I could give 2 correct answers, tried this, and it worked as well!

Comment: @Steven If you don't change **all** subvalues, you will obtain wrong results for subtotals with tax amount > 1000.00 (i.e. subtotal = 14000.00) because the subtotal issue will affect tax amount format (1000.00 => 1,000.00)